# How to get diagonal matrix $D $ from matrix multiplication of $S^{-1}$, $P,$ and $S$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am multiplying three matrices that should give me a diagonal matrix but instead of zeros for the other entries I get very small numbers. Can someone explain what is going on here and how I can fix it? This is what what I've been doing:

```
P = {{.7, .15, .15}, {.2, .8, .15}, {.1, .05, .7}}
(* {{0.7, 0.15, 0.15}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.15}, {0.1, 0.05, 0.7}} *)

S = {{7, 0, -2}, {10, -1, 1}, {4, 1, 1}}
(* {{7, 0, -2}, {10, -1, 1}, {4, 1, 1}} *)

Inverse[S].P.S
(* {{1., -1.38778*10^-17, 0.}, {-6.66134*10^-16, 
  0.65, -5.55112*10^-17}, {1.66533*10^-16, -1.38778*10^-17, 0.55}} *)
```

Comment: `Chop[%]` gives `{{1., 0, 0}, {0, 0.65, 0}, {0, 0, 0.55}}` floating point calculation noise.

Answer (score 6):

For exact results, use exact input:

```
p = {{7/10, 15/100, 15/100}, {2/10, 8/10, 15/100}, {1/10, 5/100, 7/10}}
s = {{7, 0, -2}, {10, -1, 1}, {4, 1, 1}}
```

then

```
(Inverse[s].p.s) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When using floating points, there is always chance of noise generated. `Chop[]` can be used to clean the final output

```
p = {{.7, .15, .15}, {.2, .8, .15}, {.1, .05, .7}}
(res = Inverse[s].p.s) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Chop[res] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can always convert final result to floating point (which is more accurate than using floating point during the computation, but sometimes (many times?) of course we can not avoid doing the intermediate steps using floating point), but at least in Mathematica you have the choice.

```
p = {{7/10, 15/100, 15/100}, {2/10, 8/10, 15/100}, {1/10, 5/100, 7/10}};
(N[Inverse[s].p.s, $MachinePrecision]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]